# jsdt plugin doesn't work on eclipse luna

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I downloaded JSDT plugin from Eclipse Marketplace.

Afterwards added JQuery library in *Project Properties > Include Path* and still javascript IntelliSense doesn't recognize any javascript code.

I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.

Comment: Ok, and your question is...?

Comment: how to fix this problem ? ctrl+space doesn't show any jquery event when i am coding jquery